# How do you deal with the designing issues of a website?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

We created a website few years ago and it worked all well except we are not designers so designing was very poor. 3 years later now client asked us to change the design of the site completely. We did change the design but now many (infact all pages) has few styles that are not even available in the new css file. The site is comparitively large. If we go into every single page to check for styles and classes applied to the element it would 15-20 days of unproductive work and we will already miss the deadline. How do you all deal with these issues?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You make them pay for it.

Then you can afford to pay someone to do the work.

If they refuse to pay for it, you tell them this is out of scope and either it won't be done or it will massively delay your deadline.

Comment: And while your doing it you make sure that the pages are built with clean, semantic HTML best practices so that when the client changes their mind next time you can charge them the same but do very little work :-)

Comment: Clean semantic html should be part of every organizations' coding standard.